# Asymptotic behaviour of the solution of the o.d.e $\dot{\theta}(t) = \left(\frac{A}{\langle v,\theta(t)\rangle} - B\right)\theta(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the solution of the o.d.e of the form:
$$\dot{\theta}(t) = \left(\frac{A}{\langle v,\theta(t)\rangle} - B\right)\theta(t)$$
where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $v$ is a $n \times 1$ vector.

Comment: How do you define $\frac{A}{v^T}$?

Comment: @msm:Please see the edit.